# if $f(a)f'(a) \geq f(b)f'(b)$ show that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)f''(x) \cdot dx \leq 0$

Tags: calculus

> let $f$ be continuous and differentiable twice in $[a,b]$ and $f(a)f'(a) \geq f(b)f'(b)$ show that $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} f(x)f''(x) \cdot dx \leq 0$

How should I approach it?

Comment: Hint: Let $g(x) = f(x)f'(x)$. Then $\int\limits_{a}^{b}{g'(x)\text{ d}x}\le 0$. Now what is $g'(x)$?

Comment: Integration by parts.

Comment: but $g'(x)=f(x)(f'(x)f''(x))$ so it should be $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{g'(x)}{f(x)}$?

Comment: ^double check your formula for $g'$.

Comment: @JoeyZou sorry it is $g'(x)=(f'(x)f'(x)+f(x)f''(x))$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(x)f''(x)\,dx&=\int_a^b \left((f(x)f'(x))'-(f'(x))^2\right)\,dx\\\\
&=f(b)f'(b)-f(a)f'(a)-\int_a^b (f'(x))^2\,dx\\\\
&\le 0
\end{align}$$

since $f(b)f'(b)-f(a)f'(a)\le 0$ and $\int_a^b (f'(x))^2\,dx\ge 0$.

Comment: The 2rd move I understand is integration by parts, what is the 1st move?

Comment: @gbox I don't quite understand the question.  This development is effectively integration by parts.

Comment: Why $\int_a^b (f'(x))^2\,dx\ge 0$? it can be a very small negative value such that $f(b)f'(b)-f(a)f'(a)-\int_a^b (f'(x))^2\,dx\leq 0$

Comment: The square of any real-valued function is non-negative.  Assuming $b\ge a$, the result follows immediately. ;-))